# If statement for User Authorisation

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, firebase

I have created an if statement for my code for a login and im trying to get the button to use an if statement so that if the Users details are authorised then they can be given access to the page.

The problem that I am having is that i would like to get the submit button to verify that the user is authorised and redirect them to another page, however if login details incorrect they should not be able to login

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   if ((isset($_POST['email']))  && (isset($_POST['password'])) ) {
        if (isAuthenticate($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']))
         header("Location: roster3101.php");
         exit();
   }
}

header("Location: index.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="" name="author">
    <link href="../../favicon.ico" rel="icon">
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js">
    </script>
    <title>Shifts</title><!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="softwareproject.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script src="ie-emulation-modes-warning.js">
    </script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body background="dark.jpg">

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="20px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <img height="375" src="logo10.png" width="375">
                    </center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form id="frmLogin" role="form">
         <h2><font color="white">The Online Roster</font></h2>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtEmail"><font color="white">Email address</font></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtPass"><font color="white">Password</font></label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPass" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
        </div><center>
        <button type="submit" class="rosterclicks">Login</button></center>


    </form>


                    <!-- <form class="form-signin">
                        <center>
                            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">The OnlineRoster</h2>
                        </center>
                        <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmail"></label>
                        <input autofocus="" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address" required="" type="email">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="inputPassword"></label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                    </form> -->
                    <center>
                        <table border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- <form action="roster3101.php">
                                        <input class="rosterclicks" type=
                                        "submit" value="Login">
                                    </form> -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
<script>

// Create a callback which logs the current auth state
function authDataCallback(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
  } else {
    console.log("User is logged out");
  }
}
// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
var ref = new Firebase("https://shiftsapp.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);

function authHandler(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
}

ref.authWithPassword({
  email    : 'test@shiftsapp.com',
  password : 'password'
}, authHandler);

function isAuthenticate(email, passwd) {
var ref = new Firebase("https://shiftsapp.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithPassword({
  "email": email,
  "password": passwd
}, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    return true;
  }
});
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Format your code correctly, shrink down your code to the absolute minimum to show your problem, then people will be more able to help.

Comment: @MikeC sorry about that mike! i have now changed the code to only the parts i think are relevant.

Comment: And the problem you're having is...?

Comment: @j08691 i would like the Login Submit button to verify the user is correct and then redirect to a different page.

Answer (score 2):

`isAuthenticate` is a javascript function. You can not use it as a php function. You need to write a php function which handles auth stuff.